# Format for targeting Word and LaTeX?

Tags: pandoc, msword, word-to-latex, latex-to-word, pandoc-citeproc

I'm writing a thesis, currently I have the introductory and concluding chapters in LaTeX, and all the chapters inserted in between with [`\includepdf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) (as exported from Microsoft Word).

LaTeX is far superior to Microsoft Word, however I do plan to turn some/all the chapters into conference papers / journal articles. Unfortunately most of the publishers/editors I plan to send to only accept `.doc` or `.docx` formats.

How would you recommend I proceed?

At one stage I had a pipeline from Markdown to Word|LaTeX using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) and [pandoc-citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc). Is this the recommended approach? - BTW: I've got images, a small number of mathematical equations, code, tables, and use [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org) for citation management (which exports to [bibtex](http://www.bibtex.org) &etc.).

Comment: Single-source publishing definitely is a great way to do this. It would help, though, if you would fill us in on which field are you working in. Do you need to typeset math, different languages, or charts and graphs? If your requirements are rather basic, you could try LibreOffice and its [Writer2LaTeX](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/writer2latex-1)-extension. It works well, but certainly requires some cleaning of the produced LaTeX-code. Give it a go and see.

Comment: My industries include: epidemiology, medical education, biomedical engineering, and AI in Medicine (surprisingly few support LaTeX). I tried the LibreOffice approach about 8 years ago, and it worked well enough, but as you say there was a lot of added crap like whitespace, `\\`, layout, fonts &etc. that needed to be fixed. - Was going to try this https://github.com/transpect/docx2tex also. - Though I can spend a day converting my whole thesis to some other format. - LaTeX is my preference, markdown a close second…

Comment: The ultra-clean option in the extension is pretty good, actually. Maybe it is worth another look. pandoc certainly is the best tool for the task I know of. This would be my recommendation. Another recommendation – although you probably won't be fond of hearing – is … Microsoft Word. I know, I know, LaTeX is far superior. But when it comes to professional decisions one has to be rational. If all the publishers require Word documents, there's really only one thing to say: „When in Rome, do as the Romans do.“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussions here and on `#latex` on Freenode, I've decided to convert the .docx to LaTeX, and then rewrite all my chapters in LaTeX natively (not with the Markdown intermediary).

Experimenting with chapter 1, and found that:

- [Writer2LaTeX](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/writer2latex-1): Ultra-clean adds a lot of [`\bigskip`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cbigskip-_0026-_005cmedskip-_0026-_005csmallskip.html), [`\selectlanguage`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel), screwed up the references, and missed the section/subsection headers. - Still though, it's reasonably clean…
- [docx2tex](https://github.com/transpect/docx2tex): Seems to be a little better, `\textemdash` is inserted, `\pagebreak` is also…, `\textbf` is used for my sections, tables are a little neater, references are neater but just an `\begin{enumerate}` with `\item`

---

Looking forward to huge advantages from having everything in vanilla LaTeX (no `\includepdf`s):

- Chapter bibliography
- Generate whole-thesis reference list
- Glossary integration
- Expand table of contents to include hyperlinked sections and subsections from each chapter
- Consistent reference style, changable with one line
- Consistent typeset, changeable by changing global settings in one place (`.cls`)

---

Decided not to go with the Markdown solution, as any fancier layouts becomes harder to understand and implement. Also, in terms of opening it up to external collaborators, can integrate directly with overleaf—or if I can be bothered, an open-source equivalent that I build—which my university subscribes to.

Answer (score 2):

We have two concepts:

1. Word / Libre Office: Picture on screen is supposed to be an accurate preview of printed version or PDF. Sounds consumer friendly, but it isn't, because nearly all of the layout commands are hidden and difficult to adapt.
2. Editor concept: Author types his text in a kind of editor, including some layout commands and later produces a PDF / HTML / DOCX, whatever. Disadvantages: You have to learn the commands and to figure out how to produce the PDF (e.g.) from your text.

The second concept is much easier on the long run.

The idea to use Libre Office instead of Word, because you easily can produce Word and LaTeX files, combines the disadvantages of both concepts. Besides that, even the ultra-clean option of writer2latex produces a lot of noise.

The easiest way is to take a LaTeX file and produce Word via make4ht (formerly known as tex4ht). The very active maintainer of make4ht is even here on tex.SE.

For a certain kind of my texts this is my way, because once established for a certain kind of text (with the same set of packages), it works.

But sometimes I have text which may later be used in an e-mail, in a PDF or in a docx. Getting an e-mail out of LaTeX?

There is a thing called [orgmode](https://orgmode.org/). About ten years ago I decided to learn how to use emacs with orgmode and it works. I can publish from the *.org file in any direction and it offers a lot of structure. If you are a person who lives on typing, have a look.